# Web Controls Not Talking to Each other in ASP.NET using VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp.net page that loads two controls, Control A and Control B. Control A has some generic form submit and clear buttons that trigger click events in its' own code behind which use reflection to call the update function in Control B which has a few input fields. I have debugged this and everything seems to be in order, however; when the update function in control B is called the input fields are not returning a value when using inputname.text or me.inputname.text. Does anyone have any ideas why this is not working? Any guidance would be appreciated.

This is the code in Control A's codebehind which calls the update method in Control B's code behind

```
    Protected Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Try
        Dim lctlControl = Session("SelectedQstnCtl")
        Dim methodObj = lctlControl.GetType().GetMethod("UpdateGenInfo", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
        ' Execute UpdateGenInfo method to update the data 
        methodObj.Invoke(lctlControl, Nothing)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'TODO: check for concurrency error here
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is the update function in Control B that is being called. The session values are being passed, but the form fields are not.

```
Protected Sub UpdateGenInfo()
    Dim lclUtil As New clUtility
    Dim genInfo As New clGenInfo
    Try
        Dim dt As Integer
        'Update Data for 1-2
        dt = genInfo.UpdateGenInfo_E1_01_02(Session("ConnStrEP"), Me.varLastUpdate, Session("AppNo"), Session("RevNo"), _
                                          Me.txtPrName.Text, Me.txtPrAddr1.Text, Me.txtPrAddr2.Text, _
                                          Me.txtPrCity.Text, Me.txtPrState.Text, Me.txtPrZip.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Display error
        lclUtil.DisplayMsg(Me.lblErrMsg, String.Format("Error Location: Sub LoadGenInfo (ctlE1_01_02) {0}", ex.Message))
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like a good question but you should really provide us with a code sample otherwise it's virtually impossible to see what is going on. Please add a sample of your code where you expect things go wrong.

Comment: I updated the post to include the code.

Comment: I strongly suggest you get rid of those try/catch blocks so that you can see any exceptions that may occur.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is that the control instance stored in the session is not the control instance on the current page. For example, if you're storing the control instance in the session when the page is first loaded, and retrieving it on post-back, it will be a different instance.

If you can't give Control A a direct reference to Control B, then change your code to store the reference in the `Page.Items` collection:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Page.Items("SelectedQstnCtl") = TheSelectedQstnCtl
End Sub

Protected Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim lctlControl = DirectCast(Page.Items("SelectedQstnCtl"), YourControlClass)
    lctlControl.UpdateGenInfo()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using reflection which might be an overkill for that task.Try referencing the method in the control directly.Make then method UpdateGenInfo public and then reference it like this.

```
Protected Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
Try
    Dim lctlControl = CType(Session("SelectedQstnCtl"),YourControlClass)
    lctlControl.UpdateGenInfo()
Catch ex As Exception

End Sub

Public Function UpdateGenInfo()
 'your code here

Catch ex As Exception

End Try
 End Function
```

This way you can easily trace where your values are getting lost.Let me know how it goes.

Try yet another simple  approach working demo [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/81286708/WebApplication7.zip)

In control a

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim testb1 = CType(Me.NamingContainer.FindControl("testb1"), testb)
    testb1.UpdateGenInfo()
End Sub
```

In control b

```
 Public Function UpdateGenInfo()

    Try

        Dim a = Me.TextBox1.Text
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Function
```

**Aspx** Parent Page

```
    <uc1:testa ID="testa1" runat="server" />
    <uc2:testb ID="testb1" runat="server" />
```

The controls in testb are in an update panel.Try this and let me know if this works.

Comment: No change. I ran it through debug in visual studio and everything is firing, but the input values are not being retained.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.Lets try isolating the problem first.I.Put a  test button in control B,invoke the update  method and see if you have values in the code behind in debug mode, only using control B.If you have the values then we can go to troubleshoot A.

Comment: I created a test button in control B that fires the UpdateGenInfo function. This is working as intended and all the input variables are being passed. It seems that something is being lost when I try submitting the form from Control A

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys but nothing seemed to work. I decided to simplify the solution by including the submit buttons in the control where the rest of the form lives.